Spring Data JPA AND condition with LEFT JOIN
I have the below query which joins 2 separate tables. To improve the performance, I want to add an additional AND condition. How can it be done in JPA/Hibernate?
select *
from Table A
LEFT JOIN Table B on A.column1 = B.column1 AND A.column2 = B.column2 
AND B.column3 > '100'.

In the above sample query, we have to dynamically pass the value of column 3. Tried Filter condition, but it is not working.
Tried Filter annotation but it is not working. I also tried criteriabuilder and use ON condition but it is creating an additional JOIN condition instead of appending the AND condition.

You can pass it using a param
select *
from Table A
LEFT JOIN Table B on A.column1 = B.column1 AND A.column2 = B.column2 
AND B.column3 > :paramValue
List<A> findTest(@Param("paramValue") double paramValue);

